# Reproducir SHOUTcast DNAS sin entrar en el panel de administración

Tags: navegador-web

necesito que la URL de un streaming SHOUTcast se reproduzca en el navegador **sin** entrar al panel de administración y **sin** agregar **"/;"** ni **"/stream"** al final de la URL.

Les pongo el ejemplo de 2 URL de streamings SHOUTcast en donde uno hace lo que deseo y el otro no.

Si abres este streaming [A](https://stm6-ssl.painelcast.com:6934) en Mozilla Firefox verás que aparece un reproductor y reproduce el sonido.
Ahora si abres este streaming [B](https://audiossl.radiosolution.info:9625) en el mismo navegador verás que se dirige al panel de administración de Shoutcast.

(*Les aconsejo verlo en Mozilla porque si lo hacen en Chrome o cualquier navegador basado en Chromium, el reproductor no se verá porque estos últimos navegadores descargan el streaming en lugar de mostrar el reproductor*.)

Para lograr lo mismo que el streaming A, bastaría con agregar una barra y un punto y coma al final del streaming B ó "/stream" y resultaría [esto](https://audiossl.radiosolution.info:9625/;).

Pero esa solución no me sirve para un proyecto que estoy testeando, *necesito que la dirección del streaming termine en el puerto sin nada más adelante*, igual que el streaming A.

He buscado información en Internet por más de una semana y no he encontrado nada de como lograr esto.
Alguien que me ayude por favor.

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado el problema de otra manera.
He creado variables independientes para las URL del sonido y los metadatos.
Para obtener los metadatos he usado `https://host:port`
Y para el sonido `https://host:port/stream`
De esta forma evito que el navegador me reconozca el streaming como html y se reproduzca sin problemas y los metadatos los obtengo correctamente. :)